# What is the difference between に限って and だけ?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Both に限って and だけ seem to be used with the meaning of "only".

For instance, both phrases seem to have the same meaning:

> - このスーパーは土曜日**だけ**配達する。
> - このスーパーは土曜日**に限って**配達する。

Is there any difference between them and their usage?

Comment: Is there a difference between "only" and "limited to" in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Both に限って and だけ seem to be used with the meaning of "only".*

Yes, they do. But I'd avoid to use に限って in this way (especially when I speak) because it's prone to be misunderstood as its second idiomatic senses (loaded a lot), that are:

**With negative sentence**: "the last *something* (to V)", often advocative.

> 彼に限ってそんなことするわけない！ *He is the last man to do such a thing!*

**With positive sentence**: "on the particular *time*", "*time* of all *times*", in mortifying situations.

> 今日に限って目覚ましが鳴らなかった。 *My alarm clock failed me today of all days.*

An alternative is に限り, which is almost interchangeable with だけ, only sounds quite a bit formal or businesslike.